# Unable to pass indexpath.row integer to 2nd view controller

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, segue

Please take a look at the segue code below. There are two controllers.  The 1st controller is a tableview that has a variable "activeRow" which is an integer that identifies the selected indexPath row.  The variable "activeRow", via segue, is then passed to a second view controller that has a label that displays the selected indexPath row. Nothing complicated.  When I run the code, the label on the second view controller always displays "0" regardless of the index path.  "0" is the initiating value for the variable "activeRow."  However, the print functions I inserted in the code (see below) show that the value of "activeRow" is changing according to the selected indexPath row of the tableview. Of note: when I run the simulator, the console prints "segue function: " twice.  For example, if the indexPath value is 1, the the following is printed to the console: "segue function: 0" and "segue function: 1"

In any event, the value of "activeRow" is not being passed via the segue.

However, if I remove the "activeRow" variable from secondViewController.labelTxt and simply give it a string value: secondViewController.labelTxt = "Test" then the string "Test" is passed to the second view controller and displayed via the label.

Any thoughts?

Sample Code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    activeRow = indexPath.row

    print("This is the active row selected: \(indexPath.row)")

    performSegue(withIdentifier:"sendToDetailView", sender: nil)
}


override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if segue.identifier == "sendToDetailView" {

    let secondViewController = segue.destination as! DetailViewController

    secondViewController.labelTxt = String(activeRow)

    print("segue function: \(secondViewController.labelTxt)")

}
```

Second View Controller code

```
import UIKit

class DetailViewController: UIViewController {

    var labelTxt = ""

    //var activeRow = 0

    @IBOutlet var testLable: UILabel!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

       testLable.text = labelTxt

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think the UILabels are instantiated yet. Put a breakpoint after let secondViewController =, then check the labelTxt variable. Pretty sure it's nil, hence not being able to set the text. Set it as another variable in the second VC, then assign it in view did load from that variable.

Comment: Where in your second view controller do you put `labelText` into the label?  Please show that code

Comment: Make sure you haven't linked the segue directly from your table view cell in the storyboard.  The "Action" connector for your cell should be blank

Comment: try initializing the var labelTxt in first view controller. I hope it helps you out

Comment: Paulw11- what do you mean when you write that the "Action" connector for your cell should be blank.  Currently, the segue is linked from the table cell to the second view.  It is a "push" action.   I did this because the event triggering the segue is a tap on the tableview cell.

Comment: I stumbled across a solution; however, I do not know why the solution worked.  I deleted the segue.  I added a button to the 1st view and created a push segue to show the second view.  The segue worked.  I then created a second push segue connecting the cell of the table to the second view.  I added the segue identifier.   The segue passed the index path row integer variable to the second view controller, and, after converting to a string, published the integer to a text label related thereto.  I have no clue why it works now.

Answer (score 1):

Pass the `indexPath` as the segue sender so it can be passed to the `DetailViewController` in the segue preparation. A `didSet` block will execute when the controller is passed the `indexPath`.

The outlets have not been loaded in `prepare(for segue:` so by using the destination's view in the switch statement, we are automatically unwrapping the value and the view is being loaded.

**MasterViewController.swift**

```
// MARK: UITableViewDelegate

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    performSegue(withIdentifier:"sendToDetailView", sender: indexPath)
}

// MARK: Navigation

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    switch (segue.destination.view, segue.destination, sender) {
    case let (_, controller as DetailViewController, indexPath as NSIndexPath):
        controller.indexPath = indexPath
        break
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

**DetailViewController**

```
// MARK: Outlets

@IBOutlet var testLabel: UILabel?

// MARK: Properties

var indexPath: NSIndexPath? {
    didSet {
        testLabel?.text = indexPath?.row.description
    }
}
```